# Could not build shared library using toolchain arm-uclinuxeabi

Tags: shared-libraries, cortex-m, toolchain, uclinux

When i build the shared library with toolchain GNU toolchain for uClinux Cortex-M3/M4

The following error occurs:

/arm-2010q1/arm-uclinuxeabi/bin/ld.real: error: no memory region specified for loadable section `.dynsym'

Need help please !

Comment: Interpreted literally, it's saying you are trying to link a binary without a linker map which specifies where to put this section.  However, what it probably indicates is that you are mistakenly asking the toolchain to link a binary, rather than link your objects together into a shared library which you could later use in programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the GNU toolchain version properties. you can get this arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -v in the command line.

if the tool chain is builded with --disable-shared, you will not be able to create shared library.

so when you build an utility you need to use same argument while configuring the build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The toolchain itself could not build shared library